AppCenter for Xamarin Forms is not working
I am working on a Xamarin Forms application and I have separated out the logging completely from the Xamarin forms and created a separate library (.net standard 2.1) and using abstract factory pattern. creating logger instance using different loggers such as App Center, Amazon Cloud watch, File Logging, Console Logging.
While creating the factory for AppCenter, I am configuring the app center instance
  AppCenter.Start("ios={Your App Secret};macos={Your App Secret};android={Your App Secret};uwp={Your App Secret};windowsdesktop={Your App Secret}", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
here is sample snapshot
case LoggerType.AppCenter:
    if (!AppCenter.Configured)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(configuration.AppCenterAndroidKey))
            throw new ArgumentException("AppCenter key is missing.");

        AppCenter.Start($"android={configuration.AppCenterAndroidKey};ios={configuration.AppCenteriOsKey};",
                      typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
    }
    return new AppCenterLoggerProvider();

and then logging exceptions, events through out the code. The app center code doesn't throws any error but when I am checking the app center online , then under diagnostics, events nothing is getting logged.
Is it mandatory to call the AppCenter.Start in the app.xaml.cs or MainActivity.cs?
I tried to diagnose it in different way, calling early, just after initialization of the app center instance, then also it is not logging anything to the app center.
What could be the reason here?
Is it mandatory to call the AppCenter.Start in the app.xaml.cs or MainActivity.cs?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/retirement

that's fine, we will be migrating to some other service after appcenter will sunset. but for now, we are trying to make it working. It was working fine when it was in the Forms project itself.

How long are you waiting before checking the logs?  It takes some time for data to propagate to AppCenter and get processed
